# Web.config in subdirectory causing 500 internal server error

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-config

I have a working ASP.NET web application. I'm trying to enable SSL using Let's Encrypt and to do this my shared web host host (A2) adds a web.config in the .well-known/acme-challenge directory. (All this web.config does is to bind extensionless files to plain text).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension="." mimeType="text/plain" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The issue is the mere presence of a web.config in a subfolder seems to cause any request for resources from this folder to fail, returning a 500 error. I've even tried a completely empty web.config in this folder and that still causes 500 errors. My understanding is that ASP.NET should support additional web.configs in subfolders but I have no idea why it isn't working.

I have a web.config in my root folder with the proper binding for extensionless files but the A2 Let's Encrypt tool insists on adding its own into the subfolder. I do not have any attributes preventing overridding in this web.config.

I've searched extensively for how to fix this but most of the solutions I see require changing IIS configuration. As this is a shared web host, I have extremely limited control over IIS, so that is not a viable option.

Comment: What is the sub code of the 500 error? Usually you can only see this when the error level is set to detail. But knowing it quickly narrows the problem.

Comment: After piece by piece deleting parts of my root web.config, I found that deleting the `staticContent` section allowed the subfolder web.config to work properly. I have no idea why this was causing problems, the MSDN documentation doesn't say anything about it not supporting overrides.

Answer (score 1):

Can you add this to your root web.config:

`<customErrors mode="Off" />`

... which will then result in some more error information included in the 500 response? That could provide some hints as to how to properly fix this.